# Tkinter not working

Tags: python, idle

I recently installed Python and IDLE from synaptic. However, when I test Tkinter I get the following error:

```
import Tkinter

Tkinter._test()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3790, in _test
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/local/src/tcl8.6.1/library/tk8.6 /usr/local/src/tcl8.6.1/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /usr/local/lib/tk8.6 /lib/tk8.6 /usr/library

This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

However, I have installed tk using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.6 tk-dev
```

I have no idea what is going on. In order to install the module environment I have compiled `tcl8.6.1` from source in `/usr/local/src/tcl8.6.1`. Could that be the problem?

Thank you

best,

Tom

Comment: Yes based on the `/usr/local/src/...` path mentioned in the error it is likely that your locally-compiled tcl is the issue. There may be some tcl-specific environment variables (`TCL_LIBRARY` or `TCLLIBPATH` perhaps?) that you can set as a workaround.

Comment: Yes I used the TCL_LIBRARY environmental variable to set the path to /usr/local/src/... The problem is that I do not know where tk.tcl is located upon a fresh IDLE install.

Comment: It's  probably somewhere like `/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6` but you should be able to check by invoking the system version of tclsh (e.g. `/usr/bin/tclsh`) and typing `info library`.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the tk8.6 directory in /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 to usr/local/lib and it works find now!